# Recognition of letters in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am conducting an experiment to recognize letters using a neural network.

Here are screenshots of my experiment:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to plot the error learning neural network and pattern recognition errors schedule?

Comment: If you are concerned about your English, you might be interested to know that there is a [Russian version of SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) as well. You're welcome to use both sites, of course in their own language.

Comment: The error in learning is already plotted, no? Can you try to describe better what do you need?